# nonlinsolve in SymPy giving imaginary solutions when symbols are real

Tags: sympy, solver

My symbols were all created as reals (using `real=True`). If I use `nonlinsolve` to solve for `x_1^2+1` I correctly don't get any solutions. However, a more complicated system of equations results in imaginary solutions. Am I misunderstanding how `nonlinsolve` works?

```
# Create real symbols x_1,x_2,...,x_18
syms = [Symbol('x_{}'.format(i), real=True) for i in range(1,19)]
for i,s in enumerate(syms):
    exec('x_{} = syms[{}]'.format(i+1, i))

# This code respects the real attribute
test = [Eq(eq) for eq in [x_1*x_1+1]]
print(nonlinsolve(test, x_1))

# This code violates the real attribute and gives imaginary solutions
test = [Eq(eq) for eq in [36*x_1 + 15*x_18**3 - 50*x_18**2 + 6*x_18 - 4, 15*x_18**3 - 50*x_18**2 + 114*x_18 + 36*x_2 - 40, -15*x_18**3 + 50*x_18**2 - 54*x_18 + 12*x_3 + 28, x_4 + 1, -x_18 + x_5, x_6 - 1, -15*x_18**3 + 50*x_18**2 - 42*x_18 + 36*x_7 + 4, 15*x_18**3 - 50*x_18**2 + 6*x_18 + 36*x_8 - 4, 15*x_18**3 - 50*x_18**2 + 54*x_18 + 12*x_9 - 16, x_10 - 3*x_18 + 2, x_11 - 1, x_12 + x_18 - 1, 36*x_13 + 15*x_18**3 - 50*x_18**2 + 114*x_18 - 76, x_14 + 1, 18*x_15 - 15*x_18**3 + 50*x_18**2 - 24*x_18 + 4, 6*x_16 + 15*x_18**3 - 50*x_18**2 + 54*x_18 - 22, x_17 + 2*x_18 - 1, 15*x_18**4 - 20*x_18**3 + 14*x_18**2 + 8*x_18 - 8]]
print(nonlinsolve(test, syms))
```

Comment: I tried your example on sympy master and got an exception which I think is a bug: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is documented that `nonlinsolve` returns both real and complex solutions:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solveset.html#nonlinsolve

Since `nonlinsolve` is part of the new solvers it works using sets and is intended to ignore any assumptions on the input symbols. You can get only the real solutions by intersecting with the set of real numbers:

```
In [10]: nonlinsolve(test, syms) & Reals ** 18                                                                                    
Out[10]: 
⎧⎛2   √10  5   2⋅√10                √10       2   4⋅√10  2   √10                3⋅√10         √10  8   2⋅√10        4   √10     
⎨⎜─ - ───, ─ - ─────, -4 + √10, -1, ───, 1, - ─ + ─────, ─ - ───, 3 - √10, -2 + ─────, 1, 1 - ───, ─ - ─────, -1, - ─ + ───, 7 -
⎩⎝3    15  3     3                   5        3     15   3    15                  5            5   3     3          3    3      

            2⋅√10  √10⎞  ⎛√10   2  5   2⋅√10                -√10        4⋅√10   2  √10   2                3⋅√10     √10      2⋅√
 2⋅√10, 1 - ─────, ───⎟, ⎜─── + ─, ─ + ─────, -4 - √10, -1, ─────, 1, - ───── - ─, ─── + ─, 3 + √10, -2 - ─────, 1, ─── + 1, ───
              5     5 ⎠  ⎝ 15   3  3     3                    5           15    3   15   3                  5        5         3

10   8        4   √10                 2⋅√10  -√10 ⎞⎫
── + ─, -1, - ─ - ───, 2⋅√10 + 7, 1 + ─────, ─────⎟⎬
     3        3    3                    5      5  ⎠⎭
```